# Handling CRUD on child objects with RESTful

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

If given the following xml request sent to a RESTful API endpoint called /catalog via a PUT (Intent to update catalog).

If the user provides additional `<book>`s that don't exist at that point in the catalog in the request should the endpoint "Create" them? or should they be ignored and a different endpoint perhaps /books be used to create them.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk103">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk104">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
      <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
      agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
      for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
      Ascendant.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk105">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>The Sundered Grail</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-09-10</publish_date>
      <description>The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters, 
      battle one another for control of England. Sequel to 
      Oberon's Legacy.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk106">
      <author>Randall, Cynthia</author>
      <title>Lover Birds</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-09-02</publish_date>
      <description>When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology 
      conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk107">
      <author>Thurman, Paula</author>
      <title>Splish Splash</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
      <description>A deep sea diver finds true love twenty 
      thousand leagues beneath the sea.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk108">
      <author>Knorr, Stefan</author>
      <title>Creepy Crawlies</title>
      <genre>Horror</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-06</publish_date>
      <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches,
      centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk109">
      <author>Kress, Peter</author>
      <title>Paradox Lost</title>
      <genre>Science Fiction</genre>
      <price>6.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
      <description>After an inadvertant trip through a Heisenberg
      Uncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problems 
      of being quantum.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk110">
      <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
      <title>Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>36.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-09</publish_date>
      <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in 
      detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk111">
      <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
      <title>MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>36.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-01</publish_date>
      <description>The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in 
      detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing, 
      SAX and more.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk112">
      <author>Galos, Mike</author>
      <title>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>49.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>
      <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
      integrated into a comprehensive development 
      environment.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

I am finding a lot on SO that talks about PUT vs POST and best practices for doing CRUD operations on a root object but I've spent the night trying to find information around how child objects should be handled.

According to http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html it isn't clear to me if this applies to child objects?

> 9.6 PUT
>
> The PUT method requests that the enclosed entity be stored under the
>   supplied Request-URI. If the Request-URI refers to an already existing
>   resource, the enclosed entity SHOULD be considered as a modified
>   version of the one residing on the origin server. If the Request-URI
>   does not point to an existing resource, and that URI is capable of
>   being defined as a new resource by the requesting user agent, the
>   origin server can create the resource with that URI. If a new resource
>   is created, the origin server MUST inform the user agent via the 201
>   (Created) response. If an existing resource is modified, either the
>   200 (OK) or 204 (No Content) response codes SHOULD be sent to indicate
>   successful completion of the request. If the resource could not be
>   created or modified with the Request-URI, an appropriate error
>   response SHOULD be given that reflects the nature of the problem. The
>   recipient of the entity MUST NOT ignore any Content-* (e.g.
>   Content-Range) headers that it does not understand or implement and
>   MUST return a 501 (Not Implemented) response in such cases.

From my understanding of REST, books are resources and should be handled through their own endpoint and an update to the catalog should only be used to add existing books to a catalog, not create them.

So in this scenario a book that does not exist would be ignored/not added to the catalog until a create request is submitted to create the book.

This would mean the user would send a POST /book to create the book, followed by a PUT to /catalog with the book in the request to add it to the catalog.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. You have two different resources here. One is named Books and the other is named Catalogs. You must design two different URIs to address each one. So in this scenario, I'd create two different resources to handle this problem. The first resource would be named as /catalogs and you must build it to receive only the book ID (one or more) that someone wants to associate with this catalog. You'll have:

```
Endpoint -> https://yourapi.com/catalogs

POST to https://yourapi.com/catalogs --> creates a new catalog.
PUT to https://yourapi.com/catalogs/1 --> updates the catalog with ID = 1.
PUT to https://yourapi.com/catalogs/2 where id 2 doesn't exist --> creates a new catalog with id=2
```

You have to send the XML below to the endpoint pointed above.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
    <book id="bk101"/>
    <book id="bk102"/>
    <book id="bk103"/>
    <book id="bk104"/>
<catalog>
```

The second resource should be /books and you must use it to create, delete, update and list books. Once you've created a book, then you can associate it with a catalog. You shouldn't use the resource Catalogs to create a Book that way. To my mind, it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is a bulk/batch update. Afaik. we don't have consensus how to do that. There are many issues here:

- PUT should be used by updating the whole resource. Since the resource is `/catalog` (so every single book in your storage) here, you have to give a representation of the whole catalog. You should consider PATCH instead, which can be used for partial update.
- PUT is idempotent. So if you send a PUT twice it should not have any side effect. That's why you can use PUT for creation only if the users give the id of the new resources. (Otherwise you would create the new resource twice.) PATCH is not idempotent, so 2:0 to PATCH.

You can find a description about PATCH here: [PATCH Method for HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789).

> With PATCH, however, the enclosed entity contains a set of
> instructions describing how a resource currently residing on the
> origin server should be modified to produce a new version.  The PATCH
> method affects the resource identified by the Request-URI, and it also
> MAY have side effects on other resources; i.e., new resources may be
> created, or existing ones modified, by the application of a PATCH.

So `PATCH /catalog` and your XML would be okay. You can decide whether you allow your users to give the id of the new resources, or you can generate it on server side.

Ofc. you have alternatives, for example you can send a book collection with `POST /catalog`, so multiple book resources will be created. You can use `PUT /catalog/?id="bk112,bk113,..."` to update a specific collection of books. Another alternative to  create everything one by one, as you already mentioned.

Be aware that we are talking about hyperlinks (`METHOD /resource-id?query <data />` + `link metadata: e.g. link relation`). So you should consider to add links to your resource representations you return by a GET and probably use a hypermedia format as well e.g. HAL+XML or ATOM+XML.

Comment: The question is: When using REST and sending an UPDATE to the endpoint /catalog to update your catalog of books. If the catalog contains books that do not exist is it best practice or "RESTful" to create it or should the book be created via a resource specify endpoint such as /books and the update be responsible for associating the book to the catalog. Trying to determine what the best practice in REST is for handling a resource containing child resources and CRUD operations.

Comment: @yycdev You can do it both ways. You can use `PUT /catalog` and send the whole catalog along with the new books. In this case the client will determine the book id by the new books and not the service. You can use `POST /catalog` and send only the new books there. In this case the service will determine the book id. You can use `PATCH /catalog` and send only the changes (not the whole catalog) along with the new books. In this case you can choose where you want to generate the id of the new books. Btw. this has more to do with following the HTTP standard than being RESTful.

Comment: I understand that you can do it all those ways, question is what is the "best practise" or "recommended" way according to REST standards. Just trying to see if one way stands out over the rest as the best practice.

Comment: @yycdev There are no such thing as REST standards. There are REST constraints. One of the REST constrains is uniform interface constraints, which tells that you have to follow for example the HTTP standard. If you really need bulk update with creationg I would use PATCH if I were you.

Comment: Regardless if this is REST or HTTP, All I am trying to figure out is if it is considered good practice to update a parent/root object with child objects that don't exist by creating them. There seems to be valid points for both sides but I was trying to find out if there is a "recommended" way. Personally I think an update catalog request to an api with a child object like a book that doesn't exist should not be created if it doesn't exist as update should handle existing objects by association only. This is simply my own opinion and I am trying to understand if it makes sense and is valid?

Comment: @yycdev In your case the most basic links are: `GET /catalog`, `POST /catalog`, `GET /catalog/book:112`. If you want to edit books, then `DELETE catalog/book:112`, `PUT catalog/book:112` or if there are too many attributes, then `PATCH catalog/book:112`. A bulk update is possible as well, but not so prevalent then these. Afaik. you create a bulk update if there is a special need for that on client side...

Comment: So you would agree that PUT /catalog when used to update a catalog should NOT create books that don't exist, those should be done through POST /catalog/book or even POST /book. Thanks.